How to avoid using php artisan octane:reload
I'm using Laravel Octane to improve the performance of my application, but I have to manually run php artisan octane:reload every time I make changes to my code to see the updates reflected in the application. This is quite tedious during development. Is there a way to automate this process or avoid having to reload Octane manually each time I update my code?
Additionally, my entire environment is containerized using Docker. Any insights on how to manage this within a Docker setup would be greatly appreciated.
I was expecting the application to automatically detect code changes and reload Octane without manual intervention, similar to how Laravel Valet or Sail handles hot reloading in development environments. I hoped this would streamline my development workflow by eliminating the need to manually run php artisan octane:reload after each change.
